# Why TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED called two times on home screen

Tags: android, accessibility, accessibilityservice

When we are coming back from any screen TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED called two time in my Accessibility Service.

```
EventType: TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED; EventTime: 451114743; PackageName: com.motorola.launcher3; MovementGranularity: 0; Action: 0 [ ClassName: com.android.launcher3.CustomizationPanelLauncher; Text: [Home screen 3 of 13]; ContentDescription: null; ItemCount: -1; CurrentItemIndex: -1; IsEnabled: true; IsPassword: false; IsChecked: false; IsFullScreen: true; Scrollable: false; BeforeText: null; FromIndex: -1; ToIndex: -1; ScrollX: -1; ScrollY: -1; MaxScrollX: -1; MaxScrollY: -1; AddedCount: -1; RemovedCount: -1; ParcelableData: null ]; recordCount: 0

EventType: TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED; EventTime: 451114877; PackageName: com.motorola.launcher3; MovementGranularity: 0; Action: 0 [ ClassName: com.android.launcher3.CustomizationPanelLauncher; Text: [Home screen 3 of 13]; ContentDescription: null; ItemCount: -1; CurrentItemIndex: -1; IsEnabled: true; IsPassword: false; IsChecked: false; IsFullScreen: true; Scrollable: false; BeforeText: null; FromIndex: -1; ToIndex: -1; ScrollX: -1; ScrollY: -1; MaxScrollX: -1; MaxScrollY: -1; AddedCount: -1; RemovedCount: -1; ParcelableData: null ]; recordCount: 0
```

This is two events which are fired at the same time while we come back form any screen.

Comment: Can you provide some corresponding code?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @Royz yes I have found the solution.

Comment: eh, what was the solution?

Comment: @minideveloper please share your solution

Comment: I downvoted, please post your solution and any additional information possible to your question that might help others.